# c# WebRequest Wont Post the whole length of data

Tags: c#, php, post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am currently having a problem.
I am trying to post my data to a PHP document but it does not get the whole value.
Somewhere in the middle it stops posting.

Does anyone know where the problem is located?
The bytearray is 7401 long. That cant be to long rigth?

My code is below:

```
public string RecieveData(string url, string postData = "")
    {

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            Stream dataStream;  

            if (postData != "")
            {
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.
                dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
            }

            request.Credentials = nc;
            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content. 
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return responseFromServer;
        /*
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Er is iets fout gegaan met verbinden");
            return "";
        }
        */

    }
```

Comment: What makes you think it stops posting? Have you used Wireshark or something similar to see what's going on at the network level?

Answer (score 0):

7401 is not too long.

My guess is that the data you are posting are not fully URL-encoded, e.g. one of the characters in the byte array causes the PhP parser to stop.  Make sure you are looking at the raw data (e.g. using Wireshark).